# Basic "C" programming error Trying to write Player's name before averages

Tags: c

This is the code I have written.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char playerName;
    int gameScores [10]= {12,5,21,15,32,10};
    int totalPoints=0;
    int x;
    float avg;

    for (playerName='A'; playerName<='Z'; playerName=playerName+1)
    {
        print("%c",playerName);
        scanf ("/%s",playerName[x]);
    }
    putchar('\n');

    for(x=6; x<10; x++)
    {
        printf ("What did the player score in game %d?". x+1);
        scanf ("%d", &gameScores [x]);
    }
    for(x=0; x<10; x++)
    {
        totalPoints +=gamesScores[x];
    }
    
    avg=((float) totalPoints/10);
    printf("\n\nThe Play's scoring average is %.1f.\n", avg);
    
    return (0)
}
```

I am running into problems around line 22 with

```
scanf("/%s",playerName [x]);
```

it keeps coming up with an error. It says that the subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector. I would like it to list the player's name before the score average. Without the scanf if just gives me the alphabet above the input not a players name.

Comment: remove  / from scanf ("/%s",playerName[x]);

Comment: `playerName + x` or, if you prefer, `&(playerName[x])`. 
Additionally, you don't initialize `x` which is another problem.

Comment: `playerName` is a single character. You also use it as your loop variable. How should this take a name? You need another variable which is an array of characters.

Comment: You aren't initializing all the elements in your array, so you may have some goofy values in there: `int gameScores [10]= {12,5,21,15,32,10};` -- you are asking for 10 elements, but only initializing 6 of them. And did you mean this: `for(x=6; x<10; x++)`?

Comment: You cannot use any user-input correctly unless you ***check the return***. There is no `playerName[x]`, `playerName` is type `char`, not an array, e.g. `char[26]`.

Comment: As a stylistic note, try to be consistent with the use of whitespace, e.g., sometimes you have function calls with a space between the function name `(`, and sometimes without. (Generally without space is preferred here.) Likewise with the weird spacing of `gameScores [10]= {` – even though whitespace is not significant for the compiler, it affects human readability, probably including your own.

Comment: Thank you everyone for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

`char playerName` is just a single `char`, one byte. C strings are arrays of `char`, terminated by a zero (NUL) character. The single character treated as a string could therefore only hold the terminating NUL, and nothing else, i.e., it can only be the empty string.

You need to define `playerName` as an array large enough to hold the name + the terminating NUL, e.g.,:

```c
#define MAX_NAME_LENGTH 100
char playerName[MAX_NAME_LENGTH + 1];
```

This would suffice for a single name, but since you have multiple players, you need an array of these arrays, e.g.:

```c
#define MAX_PLAYERS 10
#define MAX_NAME_LENGTH 100
char playerName[MAX_PLAYERS][MAX_NAME_LENGTH + 1];
```

(You can also allocate the memory dynamically, such as with `malloc`, but that's outside the scope of the question.)

Also, your `scanf` has an extra slash `/` in the format string, which causes it to fail unless each player name is preceded by a slash in the input, which I'm guessing is not the case. Maybe you were going for the backslash `\` to escape the `%`, but that is also not required here since the percent sign is only "special" in the `printf`/`scanf` format strings, not in C itself.

In a proper program you also need to guard against buffer overflow when reading with `scanf`. And should check the return value of `scanf` to verify that the input was successfully read (and perhaps retry or abort the program if not). See the documentation of `scanf` (and every other function you use) for the return values and arguments.

(Overall I would suggest learning to read lines into a buffer with `fgets`, as it may often be hard to recover from `scanf` errors in a sensible way, especially when the format strings become more complicated.)